# Bluetooth is disabled on startup sometimes in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I'm having a lot of issues with my Bluetooth. Half the time it works, but sometimes it just doesn't work on startup. I can see the Bluetooth sign on the launch panel, but it's greyed out, and it's not connecting to any devices.

Finally, I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez bluez-alsa bluez-audio bluez-btsco bluez-compat bluez-cups \
  bluez-dbg bluez-gstreamer bluez-pcmcia-support bluez-tools bluez-utils python-bluez \
  bluewho indicator-bluetooth libbluetooth-dev libgnome-bluetooth11 libbluetooth3 \
  python-gobject python-dbus
```

It started working after this, but because of some issues with my VLC, I had to run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After this, my Bluetooth stopped working altogether. This is what I could see in the Bluetooth settings:

[image]

So I did some research and I did this:

[image]

This took me right back to square one. Sometimes the Bluetooth works on startup and sometimes it doesn't. Once, when I couldn't see the Bluetooth symbol at all in the launch panel, I ran this:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

It worked after I rebooted it, but it still only works half the times on startup. I have no idea what to do about this. Can anyone help?

Edit: This solution seems to have worked so far. Run these one by one -

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
rfkill block bluetooth
sudo reboot
```

**EDIT: I seem to be back to square one. Bluetooth is either not showing in the launcher, is greyed out, or is simply not pairing with devices. It seems like every time there's a software update, this happens. Here is the output for** `lsusb; uname -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

[image]

Comment: What kernel are you using?  Please edit to include results for `lsusb; uname -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` when bluetooth isn't working. The backports had no chance of working as it doesn't affect bluetooth modules

Comment: Edited the question to include results.